# Cant install python 3.6.3 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, python

I had my python working just fine on ubuntu...until today when i accepted the ubuntu package update. Since then my python 3.6 has been broken and I cant install it again. I have tried uninstalling it, but cannot reinstall it. I am trying with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

After u try install I see this

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6-minimal
Suggested packages:
python3.6-venv python3.6-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6 python3.6-minimal
```

and it ends with this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.6-minimal:amd64.
(Reading database ... 332625 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.5-1+xenial1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.6-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.6-minimal_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.6-minimal (3.6.5-1+xenial1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.5-1+xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.6- 
stdlib_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__main__.py', which is 
also in package python3-tk:amd64 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package python3.6.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.6_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.6 (3.6.5-1+xenial1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-1+xenial1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cant seem to get install working. Anyone have a fix for this? Really dont feel like reinstalling ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem (also caused by changing ppa of python3.6 from jonathonf to deadsnakes) by removing python3-tk (which is "old" python3.6 package from jonathonf ppa).

```
sudo apt remove python3-tk
```

Also I am not sure if it helped me, but I cleaned `/usr/lib/python3.6/` after removing (python3.6, python3.6-minimal, libpython3.6-stdlib and apt autoremove)